# How do I send someone a normal text if they also use iMessage?

Tags: sms, messages, text

My brother has a Windows Phone, and an iPad. Whenever I try to text him, it sends him an iMessage to his iPad, not a text message. Since he does not always have his iPad with him, he doesn't get my texts most of the time.

Is there a way to choose when a message is sent via iMessage, or via SMS?

Right now, my solution is to have two separate contacts for him, but that is annoying.

Answer (score 11):

[image: Choose to send as text message by tapping and holding the message till you see the option to send as text.]

Comment: Hope this helps

Comment: You just have to do it right then and there.  You can't wait hours or days to send it as a Text Message (but then again, that kinda makes sense)

Comment: Yes Mike, you're right.

Answer (score 5):

Well, one way that I know you can do it is create a new Text Message, and hit the + icon.  Now, when you select your buddy, you should be able to select the phone number or the email address (since that is what your friend is probably using for iMessage).  Select the phone number and it **should** send it to his Windows Phone instead of his iPad.

Comment: How do I make that option show up, I only get the Copy option.

Comment: @DavidMiller The option to send as a text message only shows up right after you send the iMessage, if you wait and try to switch it later, it won't work.

Comment: As of MacOS Monterey, @Mike Eggleston's solution still works.  The key is to use the + icon as if you were starting a new thread.  Then choose the recipient's phone number for SMS (text), or email address for iMessage.  The message will be merged into any existing thread and color-coded blue for iMessage and green for text.

Answer (score 1):

Tap and hold the **Send** button for about 3 seconds and iMessage will switch to text message.

Answer (score -1):

compose a new message, start typing your brother's name in the box, select his cellphone number.

Comment: In this way you are not specifying if you are sending the text as an usual message or as an Apple iMessage.